# Looking for a project management tool that integrates with Outlook

Tags: pm-software

I'm looking for an easy to use project management tool that has the following features:

- Multiple projects
- Multiple clients
- Multiple employees
- Integrated in Outlook 2007/2010/2011 (calendar, email)
- ‘zoom out’ to watch all projects overview
- Time tracking
- On premise installation

I've tried some of the other tools that are recommended on PM, but they don't offer Outlook integration.

[InLoox](http://www.inloox.com/) for example does have much of the functionality, but the process looks too complicated (such as manually synchronizing tasks between Inloox and Outlook).

Another one is [MissingLink](http://www.missinglinkprojectcenter.com/), however I don't know if it allows me to assign tasks and view an overview of all projects. **Update:** I've tested MissingLink, but it feels slow and acts a bit weird in Outlook 2010 (clicking the dashboard link shows me the contacts, for example)

Comment: We actually went with [Liquidplanner](http://www.liquidplanner.com/)

Comment: Hi, Jao. Welcome to PMSE. While questions about *using* PM software to accomplish specific goals is generally on-topic, list-like or search-engine type questions are generally closed as "Not Constructive." If you could reframe your question to describe the PM process you're trying to solve, you may get better answers.

Answer (score 5):

In my organisation we are using **SharePoint Enterprise 2010** to manage projects by setting up workflows. This is a [MOSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_SharePoint) as Outlook which can be perfectly integrated and synchronised with the relevant project team.

With SharePoint we produce and manage *Dashboards*, *Metrics*, *Risks Logs*, etc... that are used not only to communicate the status of the project to the Project Board but also to our external stakeholders.

Moreover, since this is Microsoft (which tends to be the preferable option for many organisations) you can integrate other applications like InfoPath, Projects, Visio, OneNote, and so forth.

Have added few links underneath which contain supportive information:

- [Technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/ff819861)
- [Office.com](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-foundation-help/synchronize-sharepoint-2010-content-with-outlook-2010-HA101881295.aspx?CTT=1)
- [SharePoint Monitor](http://www.sharepointmonitor.com/2010/01/building-approval-workflows-with-sharepoint-server-2010/)
- [Projects on SharePoint](http://www.slideshare.net/getrichieb/managing-projects-on-sharepoint-rich-blank-july-2010)

---

***NEW CONTENT ADDED:***

I have kept an eye on other PM products and services that are integrated with MS Outlook.

- [**AtTask**](http://www.attask.com/feature-list) is online project management software that comes with turnkey integrations for Microsoft Outlook. If you check on the Feature List link you'll find in the Product Integration section that:

> *AtTask integrates seamlessly with all business-critical applications empowering managers with all the information they need to make informed and accurate decisions.*

We are currently reviewing this product with our IT Team and are considering to acquire it specially for its integration to MS products.

Additional sources have also recommended [**TouchBase-PM**](http://www.productdossier.com/TouchBase_PM.html) which also seems to be compatible with MS products. However we have not had feedback from IT yet on this one.

Comment: Thank you. I've tried Sharepoint. It seems to me that it doesn't allow me to easily get an overview of all running projects

Comment: @jao - Hi there, just added a couple of products that we are investigating and seem good fit for our requirements (the integration with MS Outlook and other MS products plays an important role in our organization too). Have a look and let me know your feedback. That could help other users (and myself) seeking for the same information. Thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

Microsoft Project has integration with Microsoft Office.

[image]

more information can be found on this url
http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/project-help/explore-the-microsoft-office-project-add-in-for-outlook-HA001084228.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was actually looking for an easy project management tool. I think MS Project does too much stuff automatically.

Answer (score 2):

[A more high-end project management solution is Invantive Vision.](http://www.invantive.com/products/invantive-vision) It is used by companies for projects between almost 0 and I think the largest ones are around EUR 700 M. It provides an online frontend as well as integration into Microsoft Outlook 2010 and 2013. It also integrated into Word, PowerPoint and Excel with add-ons. Please note that I work at the developing company. For Outlook use, you will need also Microsoft .NET 4.5.

Answer (score 2):

I could also suggest [Eylean](http://www.eylean.com/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=text&utm_campaign=DMaction). We have been using it succesfully in our projects for quite a while and it offers all of the features you are looking for.

Regarding Outlook integration, you can also get notifications on the tasks directly to your e-mail, as well as the possibility to turn an e-mail into a task on the board.

Answer (score 1):

You could try Clarizen, has a nice Outlook integration (and with many software) http://www.clarizen.com/Resources/Downloads/outlookaddin.aspx It's cloud based and with the right set of tools to control and execute any kind of project.

Comment: Thank you. I've tested Clarizen. It reminds me a lot of ms project.

Answer (score 1):

Our solution, TrackerSuite.Net ([http://www.TrackerSuite.Net](http://www.TrackerSuite.Net/)) integrates with email systems including Microsoft Outlook. It can be surfaced inside the Microsoft Outlook, and provides functions and tools including:

1. Project dashboards.
2. Task management.
3. Status reporting.
4. Document management.
5. Resource allocation.
6. Time reporting.

It leverages Outlook for:

1. Project request and approval workflow.
2. Timesheet review and approval.
3. Task assignments, schedule change notifications and status report reminders.

It also offers direct integration functions with Outlook, allowing users to drag-and-drop emails into a TrackerSuite.Net folder to create tasks and project documents.  TrackerSuite.Net also synchronizes tasks between itself and the Outlook tasks.

A free demo is available, you can register here: http://www.TrackerSuite.Net/request_demo.html

Comment: Thank you for declaring your affiliation - I wish more people did this!

Answer (score 1):

I’m very satisfied with Wrike’s Outlook addin. It just takes the interactive task view from the app and inserts it into Outlook. So your emails can be turned from simple “letters” into interactive tasks that are updated in real time and you can adjust task details or comment on tasks right from Outlook. As I’m quite a heavy Outlook user, this add-in saved me lots of time on switching between apps and I can track the work progress while I’m looking through my incoming emails
Here are more details: 
http://www.wrike.com/blog/New-Outlook-Addin-Turns-Your-Emails-Live-Tasks-and-Discussions

Answer (score 0):

We actually chose [LiquidPlanner](http://www.liquidplanner.com/). And I can recommend it:

- The planning can be viewed in Outlook (however, tasks are shown as all day events)
- It has all sorts of smart information such as estimating a possible release date, and alerts when a release date is likely to be missed
- It allows you to enter a 'Promise by' date. LiquidPlanner tells you how likely the date is going to be met
- A task can have a Delay Until date, for example when waiting for input
- Resource planning (who's available when) is pretty well done

Answer (score 0):

You better look into Latitude [project management software](http://latibiz.com)!. We're using it for timesheets, job tracking, client-project relation, email documentation, calendar appointment notification, quotes, invoices and reports. Its fast and works well with Outlook.

Comment: Hello kmanxi and welcome to PM.SE. Can you elaborate your answer? What makes this software better? How do you use it? Pay special attention to Outlook integration as this is the nature of the question. Look at the other answers for reference. Also, [How to Answer](http://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-answer) and [FAQ](http://pm.stackexchange.com/faq) seem to be good references.

Comment: Sorry for the brief answer. Latitude and Outlook can link email and notification(appointment) items with each other, e.g If I have a job notification for an employee in Latitude, it pop ups and sends a notification to Outlook.

Comment: Feel free to edit your answer including these details.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try for the ribbit collaboration tool for project management.  It has integration with Microsoft Outlook.

http://www.ribbit.net/tools/collaboration